# Applescript Xcode, I need to read a file and show changes continuously on a label

Tags: xcode, label, applescript

The code i have updates the label when i change the TextField content, but it's not what I need:

```
property aTextField : missing value
property aTextLabel : missing value

on controlTextDidChange_(aNotification)
    log aTextField's stringValue
    aTextLabel's setStringValue: aTextField's stringValue
end textDidChange_
```

I need something like:

```
property aTextLabel : missing value

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    repeat
        set MyFileTextContent to (do shell script "cat /Users/Johann/Desktop/myLabelValue.txt")
        aTextLabel's setStringValue:MyFileTextContent
    end repeat
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
```

But obviously this does not work, but I do not know how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Do you mean similar to the Unix tail -f command?  Do you want to refresh whenever the contents of a file changes?

Comment: yes, I try to refresh the label every time the text file content changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
property NSTimer : class "NSTimer"
property myTextField : missing value

on log1:sender
    performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_("log1:", missing value, 1.0)
    set myText to (do shell script "cat texFile.txt")
    myTextField's setStringValue:myText
end log1:

on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification
    performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_("log1:", me, 0)
end applicationWillFinishLaunching:
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I don't write AppleScripts.  But this will work for simple cases.  Note that most (all ?) implementations of tail -f use a delay, then stat the file for changes and then if there are changes it reads the file. So keep a variable to show the old contents and test against that.

```
on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    set oldContents to ""
    repeat
    set MyFileTextContent to (do shell script "tail  /Users/Johann/Desktop/myLabelValue.txt")
    set aTextLabel to MyFileTextContent
    if MyFileTextContent is not equal to oldContents
        set oldContents to MyFileTextContent
        set aTextField to MyFileTextContent
    end if
    delay 5
    end repeat
end applicationWillFinishLaunching
```

You will need to adjust the setting of aTextLabel.  You will need to experiment with the delay.  Finally, note that I used a tail rather than cat.  Adjust according to your needs._

Comment: obviously this will not work since the repeat within applicationWillFinishLaunching will cause the app to never open until the loop is finished

Comment: I actually ran it under Xcode 9 with some logging statements.  It worked, but I didn't set up any views/ viewcontrollers.  You can move the code to a viewcontroller and tie it to a button.  My point is that we need to poll.  It would be A LOT of work to make something like this event driven.

Comment: in any case the app would be locked showing the beach ball spinning

Comment: Just tie it to a viewcontroller and run on a background thread.  I can do this in swift, but unfortunately I don't know AppleScript.  You could even change the delay to a dispatch, but if it's on its own thread then that is not necessary.

Comment: How can I run the thread in the background? I only execute commands in the background but even so the app would be stuck ...

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you an example using swift.  Hopefully this will get you on track.  This is a simpler approach that uses `Timer.scheduledTimer`.  This is the complete code for a ViewController.  The storybook should have a label (NSTextField) called fileContents.  There is a start and end button.  Create a text file called mytext.txt on your desktop for testing.  If you are having problems getting it to work, I could post the entire Xcode project on github.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  monitorFile
//
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fileContents: NSTextField!
    var monitorTimer: Timer!

    var homeDir : URL!
    var desktopFile : URL!

    // This keeps us from updating the display when content didn't change
    var oldContent: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        homeDir = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
        desktopFile = homeDir.appendingPathComponent("Desktop", isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("mytext").appendingPathExtension("txt")

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear() {
        if (monitorTimer != nil) {
            endTimer()
        }
    }

    func startMonitor() {
        if (monitorTimer == nil) {
            // timeInterval is a double representing seconds
            monitorTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(updateDisplay), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func updateDisplay() {
        let newContent = readIt(location: desktopFile)
        if (newContent != oldContent) {
            oldContent = newContent
            fileContents.stringValue = newContent
        }
    }

    func endTimer() {
        if (monitorTimer != nil) {
            monitorTimer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    func readIt(location: URL) -> String {
        var contents = "No content"
        do {
            contents = try String(contentsOf: location)
        } catch {
            print("Failed reading from URL: \(desktopFile), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return contents
    }

    @IBAction func stopMonitor(_ sender: NSButton) {
        endTimer()
    }

    @IBAction func startMonitor(_ sender: NSButton) {
        startMonitor()
    }
}
```